# Upi payment is not working in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, payment, google-pay, upi

I am using   implementation 'com.shreyaspatil:EasyUpiPayment:2.2' for upi payment. But gpay fails the trasaction saying the transaction might be risky . PhonPe says transaction failed due to technical errors.
I dont understand what is the problem , here is the code

```
final EasyUpiPayment easyUpiPayment = new EasyUpiPayment.Builder()
                    .with(this)
                    .setPayeeVpa("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                    .setPayeeName("xxx xxxx  xxxx")
                    .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                    .setTransactionRefId("Ref" + transactionId)
                    .setDescription(description)
                    .setAmount(amount)
                    .build();

            easyUpiPayment.startPayment();
```

Comment: It says it is risky to carry on the transaction

Answer (score 0):

use this updated code in your android app

in update code use your upiid in pn and pa both parameter. don't use your name in pn parameter,
use upi in pn parameter also.

[Rahul Gunani](https://github.com/RahulGunani/Upi-Payment-in-Android-Latest-Updated-Code/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32168271)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76988284 With 
Google Pay, sometimes it works and sometimes not. I am using another library though.